# Getting the father-children relationships

Tags: c#, collections, recursion

Let's say we have a Windows app that has a TreeView and you can expand the nodes of this view and drill down to the children node, they may also have more children so now we can expand that node and go further, etc.. So in my source code I have a method `Foo(string fatherNode)` that gets the father node that we clicked on and finds the children and lists them:

the high level body of this method is like this:

```
private void Foo(string fatherNode)
{
  // call some DB scripts and grab data you need to work with.
  int numberOfKids = // get it from the thing you populated from the DB call.
  for(int i = 1  to numberOfKids)
  {
     Node Child = // grab child[i] from the list we populated from DB calls
     //Add it to the treeView
  }
}
```

Well that code is good for a UI app, where we click on a node, it runs this method once and collects the data it needs, Now I need to write another method utilizing useful lines of the method above Grab EVERYTHING at once and write the Whole information to let's say a file.

So in my head in looks like a recursive method to me. But still can't figure out the whole picture, Prob should have two collections, one for fathers, one for kids, loop through kids and make recursive call to get more kids and add them to the collection, etc

I was wondering if you can clear out the fogs, the high-level of what I need to do to, how the colections should look like, where to add to them, where to call the recursive method call, etc...**and please** don't specifically think about a "treeview" object, I just used that as an example to expalin the question better. The main thing is the structure of the Foo method that I posted. That's what I should work with.

Comment: (1) Could you provide the class for that list, so we don't think just about a TreeView? (2) What do you mean by *grab everything* ?

Comment: @AndreCalil : by grab everything: I mean the whole hierarchy of fathers and their children for ALL the fathers and ALL the children. Not just for the specific one that we can click on a treeview...Think of it like exporting the whole hierarchy of the data that a tree view can show if ALL of its nodes are expanded at once.

Comment: Does 1st comment `//call some db script` fetch data only for father node and child info and doesn't go deeper than that?

Comment: Ok. How would you like it to be presented?

Comment: @Ankush : Yes, it just loads the current one, doesn't go deeper.

Comment: @AndreCalil : That's not important, finally I want to represent this as a "SubClassOf" http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#subClassOf-def , but that's next level of work, for now I should have the whole data to be able to work with..a data that I can know Ok this father, has these chilren, so show them in SubClassOF...this fsther, has these children ,etc...so they will show in that format as a "class"  and "subclassof"

Comment: @BDotA Could you provide some feedback on my answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, even after the other answers.
However, please, check it out:

**The self-related entity (Node)**

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity() { }

    public MyEntity(string Name, int ID, int? ParentID)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.ParentID = ParentID;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

**The tree building methods**

```
    public static StringBuilder GetFamilyTree(List<MyEntity> AllTheEntities)
    {
        StringBuilder Return = new StringBuilder();

        List<MyEntity> OrderedEntities = AllTheEntities.OrderBy<MyEntity, int>(x => x.ID).ToList();

        foreach (MyEntity CurrentEntity in AllTheEntities.Where<MyEntity>(x => !x.ParentID.HasValue))
        {
            Return.AppendLine(GetEntityTree(AllTheEntities, CurrentEntity));
        }

        return Return;
    }

    public static string GetEntityTree(List<MyEntity> AllTheEntities, MyEntity CurrentEntity, int CurrentLevel = 0)
    {
        StringBuilder Return = new StringBuilder();

        Return.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", "\t".Repeat(CurrentLevel), CurrentEntity.Name);
        Return.AppendLine();

        List<MyEntity> Children = AllTheEntities.Where<MyEntity>(x => x.ParentID.HasValue && x.ParentID.Value == CurrentEntity.ID).ToList();

        if (Children != null && Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (MyEntity CurrentChildEntity in Children)
            {
                Return.Append(GetEntityTree(AllTheEntities, CurrentChildEntity, CurrentLevel + 1));
            }
        }

        return Return.ToString();
    }
```

**A small helper class**

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string Repeat(this string text, int times)
    {
        string Return = string.Empty;

        if (times > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                Return = string.Concat(Return, text);
            }
        }

        return Return;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
        List<MyEntity> AllMyEntities = new List<MyEntity>();
        AllMyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("1", 1, null));
        AllMyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("1.1", 2, 1));
        AllMyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("1.1.1", 3, 2));
        AllMyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("2", 4, null));
        AllMyEntities.Add(new MyEntity("2.1", 5, 4));

        Console.Write(GetFamilyTree(AllMyEntities).ToString());
```

**Results**

```
1
    1.1
        1.1.1
2
    2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `Foo(child)` within `for` loop. I guess that will solve your problem. If tree is huge don't recurse. Use Stack.

Comment: yeah but still not complete..how to fill my two collections of fathers and kids...to at the end know that ok, this father, has these children..this father has these children,.....

Comment: It's not two collection. It's n-ary tree. I guess you are confusing between this and simple binary tree.

Comment: Well consider a tree has a depth of 1 million. In that case recursion will throw stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a simple tree traversal algorithm. Here is a simple implementation of a DFS (Depth first search) in pseudo code:

```
TraverseTree(Tree t)
{
   DoSomethingWith(t); // like writing the contents of the node to the file.

   if (t == null) // leaf
    return;

   foreach(Tree child in t.Children) // recursively traverse the children.
   {
      TraverseTree(child);
   }
}
```

You can play with the order you execute your computation. see more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Comment: I wrote in bold font in my question that please don't think about "Tree"

Comment: @BDotA 
You asked about the structure of the recursive method, I wrote it down for you.

Comment: @BDotA you wrote `treeview`. `TreeView` is a UI control, on the other hand a `Tree` is a `data structure`

Comment: well I have no tree structure either..how am I supposed to use a code that doesn't use what I have to work with in my question

Comment: Declare a class like `class Node<T>
        {
            T Data;
            List<Node<T>> Children;
        }` and fill it recursively from DB.